# When nginx acts as wss proxy, is it possible to somehow examine the contents of the wss traffic and react to it?

Tags: security, nginx, websocket, reverse-proxy

You can set up nginx to proxy a websocket connection between a browser and a server. Can nginx inspect the contents (perhaps using a technique similar to the way the auth_request module works for ordinary https urls) of the wss traffic. Why would this be necessary? For security purposes. Need to block bad requests on the web socket connection.

Note, in general there would be dozens of commands sent on any given connection.